# How one can compute such sum?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

How one can compute this infinite sum:
$$\sum_{n>m}^{\infty} {n \choose m} ((1-p_1)(1-p_2))^{n-m}$$
Knowing that $p_1,p_2 \in (0,1)$

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start by making the substitution $k = n - m$ ($n = k + m$) to get

$$ \sum_{k = 0}^\infty {k + m \choose m} ((1 - p_1)(1 - p_2))^k. $$

By the (Generalized) Binomial Theorem, one has

$$ \frac{1}{(1 - x)^{m + 1}} = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty {k + m \choose m} x^k. $$

Therefore the sum evaluates as

$$\frac{1}{(1 - (1 - p_1)(1 - p_2))^{m + 1}} = \frac{1}{(p_1 + p_2 - p_1p_2)^{m + 1}}.$$